# Freemarker - How to split string or keep before certain dynamic substring

Tags: java, netsuite, freemarker

I have strings:

```
apple s/sl/abc
banana a/b/asf
hermit c/d/afd
```

I want to break two characters before the first "/":

```
apple
s/sl/ab

banana
a/b/asf
```

I thought item.item?keep_before("$/") would work for dynamic but need help.

Answer (score 1):

What you meant is `?keep_before("./", "r")`. Though you may want to be more specific there, but I don't know the exact syntax of the string that you try to spit.

To get the second half of the string, you could just substring: `full[firstHalf?length ..]`. Or you can use regular expression look ahead: `?keep_after(r".(?=/)", "r")`.

`?split` sadly doesn't work in this use case, because it doesn't support the `f` (first only) flag, at least as of 2.3.31 (I think it actually should).

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided could you split on the space?
If so, try:

```
item.item?split(" ")
```

If not, you might be able to use `?replace` and some regex:

```
item.item?replace(' .*?\/?', ' ', 'r')}
```

(note the 'r' in the `?replace` expression is for regex)